# How to assign the same static IP to a wired and wireless NIC?

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, ip, wired

I have a machine (18.04, will be 20.04 at some point) that has a wired NIC as well as a USB card with a wireless one. It is usually connected by cable, but sometimes the cable is disconnected (mechanically, by someone, for various reasons).

I would like to ensure that the **static IP** `192.168.10.1` is always reachable:

- either via the cable when it is plugged in,
- or via Wi-Fi when it is not.

Is there a standard (or at least reasonable) way to do this?

I saw an [answer to a question](https://superuser.com/a/1575407/60006) that was suggesting to assign this IP to the `lo` interface:

```
ip address add IP/32 dev lo
```

but I am not sure this is a reasonable approach?

Comment: Doesn't the WiFi connection automatically take over in the absence of the wired connection? When you say the cable is sometimes disconnected, is that purposefully or otherwise. Please [edit] your question rather than add to the comment trail. AFAIK the two NIC will require different IPs.

Comment: *Doesn't the WiFi connection automatically take over in the absence of the wired connection?* → it does, but it will either get its own DHCP address, or I could fix a static `192.168.10.1` for that interface as well - but I do not know whether this is a good idea, thus the question (I updated the question with the second part of your comment)

Comment: There are a number of ways of setting a static IP address, either within Ubuntu or by using the manager function of the Router. Either will do but leaving DHCP to sort it out (unless there are compelling reasons to the contrary) is the way to go imo. For  example, I use a static IP to mount and access a NAS which is connected using SAMBA and cifs through both the device and the router manager functions which would be inaccessible if left to DHCP to allocate randomly.

Comment: Having duplicate IP addresses is a violation of internet standards and will make your network not work. You can get away with detecting wired failure, cleaning up the debris, and only then bringing up WiFi with a static IP Address. Your router may complain that the MAC address associated with the IP address has changed.

Comment: @waltinator: I ended up going that way and posted an answer with the solution (there can be other approaches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use [networkd-dispatcher](https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher). It can be installed via `apt install networkd-dispatcher` but it was already installed on my system.

It creates `/usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher` and in there (among others)

- `no-carrier.d` → this is where to put the script to turn wifi **on**
- `routable.d` → this is where to put the script to turn wifi **off**

I made two scripts along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash

# must be /bin/bash, for some reasons /bin/sh does not work
# br0 should be replaced by the interface that goes up and down when the cable is plugged in/out
# wlx1cbfce22a2cc to be replaced by the name of the wifi interface

if [ "$IFACE" == "br0" ]
then
    echo "disabling wifi because cable is in"
    /sbin/ifconfig wlx1cbfce22a2cc down
fi
```

I fixed the IP of the wireless card to the same one as the wired one - only one of them is live at a given time.